# Left-inverse implies that $0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(\varphi) \longrightarrow 0$ splits.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\varphi : M \to N$ be an $R$-module homomorphism. Show that if $\varphi$ has a left-inverse, then $$0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(\varphi) \longrightarrow 0$$ splits.

Suppose that $\varphi$ has a left-inverse $\psi$. If I understood splitting correctly, then we are to show that $$M \oplus \mathrm{coker}(\varphi) \cong N.$$

So we need to define $$f : M \oplus \mathrm{coker}(\varphi) \to N$$ such that $f$ is an isomoprhism. The problem is that if we define $f$ such that $$(m, c) \mapsto \varphi(m) + c$$ the $c$ is actually an equivalence class of $N/\mathrm{im}(\varphi)$ and not an element of $N$. Is there a way to salvage this someway?

Comment: No, to show that the sequence splits you do not have to show that you have that isomorphism (the isomorphism can hold and the sequence not be split) I suggest you review your notes or textbook for the actual definition of what splitting means. You will never be able to solve this problem without knowing that.

Comment: I need to show that the exact sequence is isomorphic to $$0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow M \oplus \mathrm{coker}(\varphi) \longrightarrow \mathrm{coker}(\varphi) \longrightarrow 0$$ but wouldn't this be the same as showing the isomorphism I described? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: No, it is not the same. Finding the isomorphism you mention in the question text would only provide one of the three maps you need to find, and you have also two squares that need to commute...

Comment: I could take the two other maps as the identities? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: They in fact *have* to be identities.

Comment: So aren't I still left with the problem of showing that $f$ actually is an isomorphism? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: You don't have an f.

Comment: Well yes construct it first properly and then argue that it's an isomorphism. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: I guess we could take the representative $c$ of the equivalence class $[c]$ and map $$(m, [c]) \mapsto \varphi(m) + c \in N?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define a map $M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi \to N$ by $(m, [c]) \mapsto \varphi(m) + c$ for $c$ some representative of $[c]$, you'll run into an issue showing that this map is well-defined.

Instead, define $f: N \to M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi$ by $f(n) = (\psi(n), q(n))$, where $q(n)=[n]$ is the projection $N \to \mathrm{coker}\varphi$. Denote $i: M \to M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi$ and $p: M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi \to \mathrm{coker}\varphi$ the canonical inclusions and projections coming with $M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi$. The things we need to check are as follows (note that $f$ is certainly a homomorphism).

First, $f \circ \varphi(m) = (\psi\varphi(m), q\varphi(m)) = (m, 0) = i(m)$ since $\psi\varphi = 1_{M}$ and $q\varphi = 0$.

Second, $p \circ f(n) = p(\psi(n), q(n)) = q(n)$.

(These first two things we just showed is the commutativity of the two squares that must commute, mentioned by Mariano (and I am too lazy to bother making the diagram in Mathjax). So it remains to show that $f$ is an isomorphism.)

Third, $f$ is injective: Suppose $f(n) = (\psi(n), q(n)) = 0$. Since $q(n) = 0$ then $n = \varphi(m)$ for some $m \in M$, and then $0 = \psi(n) = \psi(\varphi(m)) = m$, so $m=0$ hence $n=0$.

Lastly, $f$ is surjective: Take an arbitrary element $(m, [n]) \in M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi$. Setting $a = \varphi(m - \psi(n)) + n$ for some representative $n$ of $[n]$, we see that $\psi(a) = \psi(\varphi(m - \psi(n)) + n) = \psi\varphi(m) - \psi\varphi\psi(n) + \psi(n) = m - \psi(n) + \psi(n) = m$ and $[\varphi(m - \psi(n)) + n] = [n]$, so $f(a) = (m, [n])$.

It's probably worth noting two things: first, the "surjectivity" proof above can give you a hint for how you might actually want to define a map $M \oplus \mathrm{coker}\varphi \to N$ to give the splitting; second, this result/problem is a special case of the "splitting lemma."